# Sitemap XML and Sitemap PHP

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, sitemap

i have on my webserver two different sitemap files

- sitemap.xml
- sitemap.php

If i call the uri **/sitemap** it open the **sitemap.xml** but i want that show the content from the file **sitemap.php**.

I write following lines in my htacces

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule sitemap\.xml sitemap.xml 
RewriteRule sitemap sitemap.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

But i have no success, can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule sitemap$ sitemap.php
RewriteRule sitemap/$ sitemap.php
```